# Restricting Payment Methods

Tags: java, paypal

Currently working on integrating paypal as one of the payment option for a financial institution.

Due to a regulation, we can accept only Bank account or Debit card as payment option. Credit cards are not accepted.

Is there a way to restrict the buyer to chose only Bank account or Debit card?

If not possible, is there a way to know the credit card or debit card information used by the buyer? if we know the number there are ways to check if it is debit or credit.

Comment: *Due to a regulation, we can accept only Bank account or Debit card as payment option* Then you cannot accept Paypal, because it is explicitly not a bank account (nor is it a debit card). *If not possible, is there a way to know the credit card or debit card information used by the buyer?* **No**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Going back to original question. Is it possible to restrict the method of payments a buyer can use to fund a specific paypal transaction?

Comment: No. And even if it were, you wouldn't be accepting a bank account or debit card (you'd be accepting PayPal, which is neither of those two specific things).